# Where do I set environment variables for Django?

Tags: django, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

everyone!

Django 1.11 + PostgreSQL 9.6 + Gunicorn + Ubuntu 16.04 in AWS

I want to set environment variables for sensitive info.(django secret key, DB password...)

I studied many articles about setting ways.

But when I tried os.environ['env_name'],

1. .bashrc: Not working
2. .bash_profile: Not working
3. .profile: Not working
4. /etc/environment: Not working
5. Gunicorn script file.(systemd): I set them in gunicorn systemd script. It work very well.

But because I want to use the environment variables in other program too, I set them among 1~5 configurations. I don't understand why 1~5 configurations didn't work. Is there scope or priority of setting environment variables?

EDIT:

I use Ubuntu 16.04 server. I can't restart terminal session.

I tried 'source .bashrc' and logout/login. But It didn't work.

Of cource, 'echo $some_env_var' is working, I say, django can't read.

Comment: Setting the environment variables in .bashrc should work. Make sure you have source the .bashrc after setting the environment variable and restarted the terminal session.

Comment: You need to make sure you're setting them for the user that is actually running the server.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04 serve. I can't restart terminal session.

Comment: Just so you know, logout/login is the same as restarting your terminal session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: but then aren't variables set in `/etc/environment` available for every user throughout the system? Why didn't that work?

Comment: For anyone using tmux to edit .bashrc in one pane and run the server in another, you have to source .bashrc in the same pane that the server is running because it's a different terminal session.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create a file called .bashrc in your server

```
export('the_name_in_bashrc', some_value)
```

then in the `settings.py`

```
import os
some_variable = os.environ.get('the_name_in_bashrc')
```

Comment: This answer is not suitable for production

Comment: For it to work on production, you need to set the environmental variables at web server level e.g where you have setup the gunicorn script.

Comment: @User why? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Exporting like gives me an error. in Ubuntu I had to do export MYVAR=1234

Answer (score 19):

.bashrc will work for local development but not for a production environment. I just spent quite a bit of time looking for the answer to this and here's what worked for me:

1) Create a file somewhere on your server titled settings.ini. I did this in /etc/project/settings.ini

2) Add your config data to that file using the following format where the key could be an environmental variable and the value is a string. Note that you don't need to surround the value in quotes.

```
[section]
secret_key_a=somestringa
secret_key_b=somestringb
```

3) Access these variables using python's `configparser` library. The code below could be in your django project's settings file.

```
from configparser import RawConfigParser

config = RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/project/settings.ini')

DJANGO_SECRET = config.get('section', 'secret_key_a')
```

Source: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings (ini-style section)

Answer (score 14):

The simplest solution is as already mentioned using os.environ.get and then set your server environment variables in some way (config stores, bash files, etc.)

Another slightly more sophisticated way is to use [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) and .env files. Here's a quick how-to:

1) Install python-decouple (preferably in a venv if not using Docker):

```
pip install python-decouple
```

2) Create a .env file in the root of your Django-project, add a key like;

```
SECRET_KEY=SomeSecretKeyHere
```

3) In your settings.py, or any other file where you want to use the configuration values:

```
from decouple import config

...

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

4) As you probably don't want these secrets to end up in your version control system, add the file to your .gitignore. To make it easier to setup a new project, you could have a .env_default checked into the VCS containing default/dummy-values that's not used in production.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using a virtual ENV you can add the environment variables to that specific environment. You can use `export KEY=VALUE` in your terminal but that will not persist. If you would like your values to persist you can edit the file:

`sudo nano your_environment/bin/activate`

Then at the bottom add the values you want e.g.:

`export MY_KEY="12345"`

And save. Remember to restart your ENV for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

> pip install python-dotenv

> Go To settings.py

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
```

> Go To .env file

```
SECRET_KEY =  your_secret_key
```