# How to find cause if error points to line with "application = get_wsgi_application()"

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a django app to pythonanywhere following their official guide; I've created a virtualenv, installed packages listed in my requirements.txt, created the web app and ammended the wsgi file listed in the dashboard as suggested. But I'm receiving this TypeEerror pointing to nowhere.

```
'''
2019-06-27 12:13:32,270: Error running WSGI application
2019-06-27 12:13:32,271: TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
2019-06-27 12:13:32,271:   File "/var/www/corebots_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 25, in <module>
2019-06-27 12:13:32,271:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-06-27 12:13:32,271: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,271:   File "/home/corebots/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-06-27 12:13:32,271:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272:   File "/home/corebots/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272:   File "/home/corebots/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272:     self._setup(name)
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272:   File "/home/corebots/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-06-27 12:13:32,272: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273:   File "/home/corebots/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273:   File "/home/corebots/portfolio_pa/WEB/settings.py", line 177, in <module>
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273:     # MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "WEB/media_cdn") # for: user uploaded
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273:   File "/home/corebots/portfolio_pa/example_storages/settings_s3boto.py", line 24, in <module>
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273:     #AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273: ***************************************************
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-06-27 12:13:32,273: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-06-27 12:13:32,274: ***************************************************
'''

head of my settings py:

'''
import os

# for importing example_settings.env as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693485/where-do-i-set-environment-variables-for-django
import environ


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME= os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY= os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
'''
```

my pythonanywhere wsgi file:

```
'''
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own Django app use code like this:
import os
import sys

from dotenv import load_dotenv

project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/portfolio_pa/WEB')  # adjust as appropriate
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, 'settings.env'))

# assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/myusername/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
path = '/home/corebots/portfolio_pa'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'WEB.settings'

## Uncomment the lines below depending on your Django version
###### then, for Django >=1.5:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
###### or, for older Django <=1.4
#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
'''
```

Comment: Can you add the steps you've tried from the help link in the error message https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/

Comment: Thank you. Actually it looks like I'm hitting this bug with boto https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3699

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error pointing to commented out lines because you have not reloaded your web app since making the changes to the code. So the web app is running the old code, but reporting the errors from the changed files.

Comment: I keep hitting 'reload web app' all the time, so I don't expect that to be the problem... It's probably this bug https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3699 so I need to find a way to either migrate the current django-photologue library to make us of the newer boto3, or find another solution.