# How to set environment variables for django project in windows using .env file? [Beginner]

Tags: django

I know how to use with python *dotenv*. but i would like to know with django-environ. Like I would like to access with `os.environ.get('')`. I know how to access but doesn't know hot to set them.

- Installed django-dotenv
- I have created .env file in my django app.
- Set variables in .env but when i try to access them in my settings.py with 
  `os.environ.get('db_name')` , it throws error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I set environment variables for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693485/where-do-i-set-environment-variables-for-django)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set DJANGO\_SETTINGS\_MODULE as an Environment Variable in Windows permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156500/set-django-settings-module-as-an-environment-variable-in-windows-permanently)