# SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/

Tags: django

I'm having this error, I'm using Ubuntu Linux os here I made env variable at a home section named ".bash_profile" in which I saved my Gmail and pass. Now the problem is when I'm calling them in settings.py file they don't work but instead of it if I try to put email and pass there, it works fine and I get the reset email. Things that I've already tried are-

1. List item
2. The same name of both the variables from the env variable and in settings.py
3. I'm not using 2FA so I allowed the less secure app.
4. Tried to use 2FA and followed the different process.
5. Mail id in Django user and this user is the same.
6. Already looked for the different answers on stack overflow and other sites.

code are as follows

settings.py

```
    """
Django settings for blog_page project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3*v_t0-f_+g1un_7k-mpt7q2=*3q+#&6!c5b1+b#$#buxwa_4e'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
    'users',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog_page.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog_page.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'lkbhitesh07@gmail.com'
```

urls.py of project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_view
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('register/', user_view.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_view.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('profile/', user_view.profile, name='profile'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_view.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

ERROR showing in terminal

```
    atching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 07, 2020 - 10:16:44
Django version 2.2.6, using settings 'blog_page.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[07/May/2020 10:16:49] "GET /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4013
[07/May/2020 10:16:51] "GET /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4013
[07/May/2020 10:16:51] "GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/May/2020 10:16:52] "GET /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4013
[07/May/2020 10:16:52] "GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Internal Server Error: /password-reset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 220, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 233, in form_valid
    form.save(**opts)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 295, in save
    email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 250, in send_mail
    email_message.send()
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 110, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/home/hitesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 126, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 867, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError t21sm3542961pgu.39 - gsmtp', 'lkbhitesh07@gmail.com')
[07/May/2020 10:17:02] "POST /password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132443
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIf9t.png)

please do let me know if I have to show any other code.

Answer (score 0):

After hustling through this all I got the solution. All you need to do is put your secret key or password in your virtual environment.

```
sudo nano virtual_env/bin/activate
```

Try this command and make sure to restart your environment and then you'll be good to go.
I know it's not kind of a perfect solution but worked for me.
The reference I took [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693485/where-do-i-set-environment-variables-for-django).

If anyone has suggestions please do tell me it'll increase my knowledge.